# .NET MAUI Does Not Fill Entire Screen on iOS (very low resolution), but is fine on Android

Tags: maui

After struggling to change the package icon and making changes to the csproj file, the application now displays in very low resolution on iOS and appears normal on Android.  This was not an issue before attempting to change the packge icon.  I have tested on iPhone and iPhone Simulator.

[Normal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS45d.png)

[Incorrect View on iOS only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1ZNx.png)

I have compared my csproj file settings as well as many others.  I cannot find a difference.

Is there a setting that controls this?

Comment: Did you perchance remove the `MauiSplashScreen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This github issue provided the workaround until resolved.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11951

--info from link above--
If for whatever reason you remove your splash screen from the .csproj file, then you get some weird behavior where the application no longer fills the screen.

At the very least, if this is required, it should produce some sort of error or warning when compiling.

This is what I removed:

```html
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

Comment: please post the relevant details.  Answers that are just links to offsite resources are not encouraged